# Is it compulsory to deploy 1_initial_migration.js every time I deploy a contract?

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

When I run `truffle deploy`, it deploys `1_initial_migration.js` before every contract. Is there anyway this can be avoided? Or is this part of protocol and is supposed to happen everytime?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove that file.

If you have multiple contracts and you sometimes update only some of them, the initial migration is supposed to make sure that only the changed contracts are updated.

In reality I haven't seen any serious project use the initial migrations. Some have the file still there, but have basically forgotten it's there and gain no benefits.